# Iterate through hash maps and object

Tags: java

I am gradually learning how to use Hashmaps , I have a map where i would be adding

`HashMap( student id, other student records as object() )` .

I am trying to retrieve the values with their keys.

Please see below.

```
HashMap<String, Object> studentinfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<Object> lstObject = new ArrayList<Object>();

studentinfo.put("student height", 5.01); //Put data in studentinfo hashmap
lstObject.add(studentinfo);


// New items hashmap 
HashMap<String, Object> items = new HashMap<String, Object>();


//Put object in items hashmap
items.put("student id 001",lstObject);  //Store data for 1st id student with  001
items.put("student id 002",lstObject);  //Store data for 2nd id student with 002



for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : items.entrySet()) {

            if(entry.getKey().equals("student id 001")){
                  //Get student id for only student id 001

                  System.out.println(entry.getValue());

                  // When i print this out , this is what i get 

                 // [{student height=5.01}]

            }
 }
```

How can i loop thru to get the value only
 Like this, for example:

```
 5.01 // Student id 001
```

Comment: `entry.getKey()=="student id 001"` - always use `equals()` to compare strings.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question but try `items.get("student id 001")` to get the value for the key `"student id 001"`. If there is no such value you'll get  `null` so handle that.

Comment: I think you are missing the main point of a `Map`, which is that you can directly retrieve values using their keys.

Comment: Ok, let me explain better, the "student id 001" key exist, and its values are [{student height=5.01}] , the problem i am having now looping through this data [{student height=5.01}] which is an object to retrieve Only "5.01" as student height....do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value `5.01` which is stored in a map for the key `"student height"` within a list that is stored in another map under the key `"student id 001"`, you'll need to code the access to that information. The outer map itself only knows of values and if you define the value type to be `Object` you'd have to cast yourself.

A better design might be to replace that list with a `Student` object which has a property `height` and access that.

But just for information, if you'd define your map like `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>` you'd be able to directly access the lists and their elements as values, e.g. (not handling null for simplicity):

```
Double height = (Double)items.get("student id 001").get(0).get("student height");
```

Just to reiterate: this is awkward design and should be changed, you'll probably realize that whith increasing experience and knowledge.

Better:

```
class Student {
  double height;

  Student(double h) {
    height = h;
  }
}

Map<String, Student> students = ...;

students.put("student 001", new Student(5.01) );

double height = students.get("student 001").height;
```

Note that I left out a lot of code for simplicity reasons such as modifiers, getters/setters, null checks etc.

*Another note (added here instead of a comment for formatting reasons):*

```
items.put("student id 001",lstObject);  //Store data for 1st id student with  001
items.put("student id 002",lstObject);  //Store data for 2nd id student with 002
```

This will put the *same* list as the value for both keys, i.e. if you change the list elements you'll change it for *both* student ids.

Comment: Thanks very much , "This will put the same list as the value for both keys" -- Yes i know this.